# In a grouped list, how to display items of an intersection of two groups

Tags: filter, categorization, grouped-list

Provided I have a category which gives x non mutually exclusive options.
I have a list of items which can be tagged with several of these mutually non exclusive options.

- Item 1

  - Group A
- Item 2

  - Group B
- Item 3

  - Group A + B
- Group C ...

A user can now select one/several of the options so they retrieve a list of items according to each options they selected and the union of these options, if needed.

- Group A -- selected
- Group B -- selected
- Group C

I have a constraint when it comes to displaying the result: the items must be grouped under the options they are tagged with.

- Group A

  - Relevant items
- Group B

  - Relevant items

This is where I am faced with a choice to make in order to display the items which are tagged with several of the select options - hence are at the intersection of several groups.

The alternatives are: display each items several times, one under each group they belong to, like so:

- Group A

  - Item 1
  - **Item 3**
- Group B

  - Item 2
  - **Item 3**

Or display a group for each intersection of groups

- Group A

  - Item 1
- Group B

  - Item 2
- Group A + B

  - **Item 3**

Solution 1 result in a duplication of the content (the item), solution 2, a duplication of the meta-information (the categories).

Now, this was an imaginary explanation. My real case implies 5 categories each with between 3-5 options and two nested grouping based on 2 of these categories. As a result, whichever solution comes with a big overload of duplicated information - just think of the possible combination of groups.
Nonetheless, I would like to have your opinions and knowledge on which would be the worse of two evils out of these two solutions ?

I might add that the value proposition I am working with for this content is partly, the number of items of content. Hence, albeit being more readable, I believe that solution 1 could be perceived as bearing disingenuity as it increase that number. Solution 2 would be worse in terms of readability though.

Of course, I am also investigating alternatives to grouping altogether but would like to put this problem out there for reflexion and see if someone comes with different angles than mine.

Comment: when you present items, how many other attributes are in the list view, and is the category a secondary concern for users? In other words, is there action the users take on the items found, and how often would they search other items in the same category? Do they explore based on similar items?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what user will do with the result to propose a possible option.